# WebView clicks opens mobile browser

Tags: android, overloading, android-webview

There is a `WebView` which loads mobile-optimized URL (webpage). But when I click on a link, it does not load inside of the `WebView` (inside of the app), but mobile browser opens.

How to prevent this?

I tried overloading URLs via `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, but it did not help.

This is a code.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 7) {
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
}
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals(url)) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    }
});
webView.loadUrl("http://some-url.com");
```

---

**EDIT**

Does `GET` or `POST` posting methods have anything with links' clicks open mobile web browser???

Comment: sorry there is true, but I did not copy it!

Comment: Does this piece of code `if (url.equals(url)) {view.loadUrl(url);  return true;}` look fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `true` instead of `false` in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

From the documentation:

> shouldOverrideUrlLoading returns True if the host application wants to
>   leave the current WebView and handle the url itself, otherwise return
>   false.

Comment: sorry there is true, but I did not copy it!

Comment: `url.equals(url)` doesn't actually do anything. They're the same Object, so of course they are equal. Why not just have `@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { view.loadUrl(url); return true; }`?