# View/display .doc,docx,xls files in Android programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view

i am working on Document fatch app and i need to show .doc,.docx,xls files from my external storage to my app as i able to view pdf using pdf viewer but not getting how to show these files.

Comment: You can try opening files inside Google docs viewer in WebView. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/28023795/1306419

Comment: opening fine inside google docs redirecting to outside the app.i have file in external storage and just wand to display in as i doing with pdf

Comment: You've to override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and return true to tell it that the app will handle it and you don't want it to redirect to the broiwser. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263367/webview-clicks-opens-mobile-browser

Answer (score 0):

There is an android branch of Java library [docx4j](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/android), you can use it. Another option is using Webview, set:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and then pass link of your document to webview (it can also be local link). I am not sure that webview solution will work on all versions of Android, so docx4j is more generic solution.